# Broken Korean strings when reading DataFrame from CSV

Tags: python, unicode, pandas

I am a Korean user.

When I read a .csv file from a Pandas DataFrame, Korean strings are broken like this: `�����`

English is good.

Input data sample:

```
Unnamed: 0  ��������    �������ε�����   ��X��ǥ  ��Y��ǥ  �����ڵ� ������  ����߻���������  ����Ǽ�  ��������

0   165244  20131201    �ٻ�62175541 962170  1955410 331 ��������    1   2   18224.03
```

Why does the Korean text get corrupted?

Comment: What is the encoding of your .csv file?  Is it save with utf8 or other encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your text format is unicode so you need to decode it as `utf-8` :

```
import csv
def unicode_reader('your_file_name',delimiter='your_delimiter', **kwargs):
     spamreader = csv.reader('your_file_name',delimiter='your_delimiter', **kwargs)
     for row in spamreader:
        yield [unicode(w, 'utf-8') for w in row]

reader = unicode_csv_reader(open('your_file_name'))
for tex in reader:
  print tex
```

Comment: i am ipython user. and I use that code. but I watch this error  ----UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Comment: so change `utf-8` with `ISO-8859-1` and give me the result !